# Помогите объяснить причины возникновения речевых ошибок в предложениях

Tags: грамотная-речь

В этих случаях и изготовляются нектары, которые полностью сохраняют достоинства фруктов и овощей.
В Пензенской области планируется разведение буйволов и более традиционных овец.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **В этих случаях и изготовляются нектары, которые полностью сохраняют достоинства фруктов и овощей.**

Редактирование: *В этих случаях и изготовляются нектары, которые полностью сохраняют **положительные свойства** фруктов и овощей.*

***Сохранять достоинство*** – устойчивое словосочетание, которое характеризует поведение людей.

2) **В Пензенской области планируется разведение буйволов и более традиционных   овец.**

Редактирование: *В Пензенской области планируется разведение буйволов и более традиционных **для этих мест** овец.*

Выражения ***традиционные овцы, более традиционные овцы***  семантически некорректны, так как имеют неясный смысл

Answer (score 0):

Первое предложение неправдоподобно, поскольку "полностью" сохранить достоинства могут только фрукты и овощи (можно говорить только о сохранении некоторых полезных свойств). Во втором предложении буйволы оказались "недостаточно традиционными овцами" (возможный вариант: "... обычных для этих мест овец").